# Select element in chrome and firefox affects CSS styling

Tags: javascript, reactjs, antd

I am building a react web application and using antD UI library, the issue I am facing is that the styling of buttons seems to be incorrect in Tablet mode.

When I press on Select element tool, the styling changes.

I wonder how can Select element affect CSS styling. [GIF Snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3wPe5.gif)

Comment: Could you explain more carefully? What does that mean by the "Select element tool"? Do you mean in chrome? If you can share a screenshot, it would be easier to understand your issue. Thanks

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Yes for sure
I have attached a gif showing the exact issue I am having https://i.stack.imgur.com/3wPe5.gif